# Notepad++: Complex Find and Replace

Tags: search, replace, find, notepad++

I have as follows:

> T47101 *UNIPROID*  **FGFR1_HUMAN**
> T47101  ECNUMBER    EC 2.7.10.1
> T47101  *SEQUENCE* **MWSWKCLLFWAVLVTATLCTARPSPTLPEQAQPWGAPVEVESFLVHPGDLLQLRCRLRDDVQSINWLRDGVQLAESNRTRITGEEVEVQDSVPADSGLYACVT**
> T47101  DRUGINFO    D09HNV  Intedanib   Approved
> T47101  DRUGINFO    D01PZD  Romiplostim Approved
> T47101  DRUGINFO    D02WVT  E-3810  Phase 3

There's a lot of filler in here. The only things I'm interested in is the words that follow UNIPROID, which are always different but always contain _HUMAN after. I want to keep that information (ex. FGFR1_HUMAN).

Then the other thing I'm interested in is everything that follows the word SEQUENCE. I want to keep the letters that follow that. Everything other than those two bolded things I want to get rid of.

I don't have much experience with using this, so I need all the help I can get.

Here is what I currently have:

Find: .+UNIPROID(\D).+

I have regular expression checked and .matches newline unchecked.

Edit: The command I have now is able to delete everything up until FGFR1_Human, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Like this? `.*?(?|UNIPROID\h+(\w+_HUMAN)|SEQUENCE\h+(\w+)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/hP3ZKm/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

**Find what:**

```
.+?(?|UNIPROID\h+(\w+_HUMAN)|SEQUENCE\h+(\w+)|$)
```

The pattern matches

- `.+?` Match 1+ times any char except a newline non greedy (lazy)
- `(?|` Branch reset group, to use group 1 for both alternations

  - `UNIPROID\h+(\w+_HUMAN)` Match *UNIPROID*, 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and capture 1+ word chars and `_HUMAN` in group 1
  - `|` Or
  - `SEQUENCE\h+(\w+)` Match *SEQUENCE*, 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and capture 1+ word chars in group 2
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string to also match the last part
- `)` Close group

**Replace with:**

```
$1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N7pscN/1)

[image]